# Django-Taggit: How to print the most used tags?

Tags: python, django

Im actually using [Django-Tagging](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit) into my django app. I would like to know if you know some way to print the most common tags. I tried [Django-Taggit-Templatetags](https://github.com/feuervogel/django-taggit-templatetags) but it doesn't work ... (here is [my unanswered question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118714/django-1-6-django-taggit-templatetags-doesnt-work-help-me-please)). Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5):

Django 1.10, Python 3.5, django-taggit 0.21.3

```
YourModel.tags.most_common()
```

and top 10 tags:

```
YourModel.tags.most_common()[:10]
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution might be hacky but it works. Try:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
from taggit.models import Tag
from .models import YourModel

tag_frequency = defaultdict(int)


for item in YourModel.objects.all():
    for tag in item.tags.all():
        tag_frequency[tag.name] += 1

Counter(tag_frequency).most_common()
```

So in a Class-based view this might look like:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
from taggit.models import Tag
from .models import YourModel


class YourView(ListView):
    model = YourModel
    context_object_name = "choose_a_name_you_like"
    template_name = "yourmodel/yourmodel_list.html"

    def get_context_data(self):
        context = super(YourView, self).get_context_data() # assigns the original context to a dictionary call context
        tag_frequency = defaultdict(int)

        for item in YourModel.objects.all():
            for tag in item.tags.all():
                tag_frequency[tag.name] += 1

        context['tag_frequency'] = Counter(tag_frequency).most_common() # adds a new item with the key 'tag_frequency' to the context dictionary, which you can then access in your template
        return context
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, but where you write this piece of code? Views.py?

Comment: Sorry been away for a while. Yes you can put this is a view, in which case you would return your count as some extra context. I'll edit the answer with an example Class-based view.